# How to number equations in braces

Tags: latex, label, equation

I want to label both equations separately, but I can't find the way. Instead, it displays only one tag for the equation.

My code looks like this:

```
\begin{equation}
    m \vec{\gamma} = F(r, \theta, \dot{r}, \dot{\theta}, t)\mathbf{u_r}
    \Longrightarrow 
    \begin{cases}
        \mathbf{u_r} \Rightarrow m (\dddot{r}- r \ddot{\theta}^2) = 
        F(r, \theta, \dot{r}, \dot{\theta}, t) \\
        \mathbf{u_\theta} \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dt}(r^2 \ddot{\theta}) = 0 
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

And it displays what is shown in the picture:

[image: LaTeX Render]

Comment: Welcome to the site! :) You might get better answers if you log into https://tex.stackexchange.com/ and ask this question over there.